# Opening app from extension, properties only change the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios8-today-widget

I have a today widget extension, and when I click a button it opens up the app. The first time I click the button and follow the code through, it uses a custom URL scheme to pass data through. That's parsed in the AppDelegate, and it figures out what data to populate the `ViewController` with. The `ViewController` is instantiated with a storyboard ID. Values are applied to one of the `ViewController`'s properties, and then in the `viewDidLoad` the rest of the values are populated based on this passed in Value. This all works the first time.

However, if I hit the home button, open notification center, tap a button in my app and go through the whole process for a second time.. I step through the code as normal, all the values get set, but when the `ViewController` gets displayed, the values (such as `UILabel`) are the same as the first time, but they should have changed.

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:string ://%@", self.expanededTubeLine.lineName ];

NSExtensionContext *myExtension=[self extensionContext];
[myExtension openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] completionHandler:nil];
```

//

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {

NSString *tubeLineName = [url host];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:@"group.koc.extensiontest"];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"weekendData"]) {

    NSData *tubeData = [[defaults objectForKey:@"weekendData"] copy];

    TFLParser *parser = [[TFLParser alloc] initWithData:tubeData];
    [parser parseData];
    for (int x = 0; x < parser.delayedTubeLines.count; x++) {

        TubeLine *tl = [[TubeLine alloc] init];
        tl = [parser.delayedTubeLines objectAtIndex:x];
        if ([tl.lineName isEqualToString:tubeLineName]) {

            UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            TubeLineViewController *tubeLineViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TubeLineViewController"];
            tubeLineViewController.tubeLine = tl;


            [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:tubeLineViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
            return YES;
        }
    }
}
```

}

//

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tubeLineName.text = self.tubeLine.lineName;
    self.tubeLineName.font = [UIFont openSansLightFontOfSize:18.0f];
    self.tubeLineName.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.tubeLineName.backgroundColor = self.tubeLine.lineBackgroundUIColor;
    self.tubeLineName.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    self.tubeLineName.clipsToBounds = YES;

    self.tubeLineMessage.font = [UIFont openSansLightFontOfSize:18.0f];
    self.tubeLineMessage.text = self.tubeLine.lineMessage;
    self.tubeLineMessage.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like the View is loaded already so pop all the view controllers before pushing the widget based controller in handleOpenURL: function.

```
  [self.viewController.navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
  if ([self.viewController presentedViewController]) {
      [self.viewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
   }
```